# Mixed qt4 and qt5 in a application

Tags: qt, qt4

I would like to know if it is possible to create a Qt application that uses the qt5 version of core library and the qt4 version of the gui library. I would like to use some features available only in qt5, like the QCommandLineParser class, but it is not possible for me to use qt5gui, only the qt4 version is working.

Comment: If you want to mix and match, your best bet is to build a custom version of Qt from source. But don't count on anyone else being able to support it.

Comment: I don't think this will work, because qt is C++.

Comment: @MrEricSir I am using a computer (without admin rights) where both qt4 and qt5 are installed, but because it runs on Suse Enterprise 11, libQtGui5 is not working (see [bug description](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38050) ). I was just wondering if it was possible to tell qmake to use version 4 for core and version 5 for gui. I guess it is not the case.

Comment: @user3183610 I don't see your point, can you please be more specific?

Comment: C++ doesn't have a stable ABI, instead have vtable etc. Qt GUI 4 calls functions in core 4 lib, when you replacing it with version 5 lib, to the minimum, all virtual table have different offset. Quite likely, you will get OS error even before wrong function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not possible, you can't link an application with mixed versions of Qt, actually you can't even compile it.. if you need something very specific you can extract from the code, but you need a commercial license for this.